# Unable to find Rolling Update Option For Managed Instance Group in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have created a Managed Instance Group (Stateless) in GCP.
The MIG has a starter script ,like this

```
apt-get install -y apache2
apt-get install -y php7.0
service apache2 restart
echo "Hi" > /var/www/html/index.html
```

The MIG is then kept as a backend for a load balancer.

- Once the MIG is created , I am tryin to add a new instance template
  and update the MIG
- I selected the MIG  and in the top of the page I expected to see a Rolling Update button , but That is not visible .
- There is a Update Vms option , through which I am able to add the new
  template. So , what would be the difference between Rolling Update
  and the Update VMs option ? When would one choose one over the other ? Or are they the same option?

[image]

This is the snap of how I am using the update Vms option to switch to a new instance template
[image]

Comment: Edit your question and add details on how you have set up and then changed the instance templates. Rolling updates apply a new instance template.

Comment: Can you describe what strategy you want to achieve?

Comment: I am able to use the update Vms icon to add a new instance template to the Vms. Does it mean its the same as Rolling Update ? Because in this link https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/rolling-out-updates-to-managed-instance-groups it specifically talks about a Rolling Update Option , I can't find it ?

Comment: Google Cloud supports instance template versions. This supports rolling updates transitioning from one version to another. If you have created a new instance template then use **replace**.

Comment: how to do it from the UI ?

Comment: Based upon the console view, you do not have an instance template configured to update to.

Comment: I have added the screenshot of I used updateVMs option to add a new template

Comment: Both instance templates are in use. For one, you have two bad instances. Either resize the good template or fix the bad template.

Comment: Also, notice the status **updating** in your screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to [Updating instances in a MIG](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/updating-migs) document, this will help you to [choose which update](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/updating-migs#choosing_between_automated_and_selective_updates) will be better for your implementation.

[Rolling update](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/rolling-out-updates-to-managed-instance-groups) The MIG automatically rolls out a new version of an instance template to all or to a random subset of managed instances in the MIG.

You can handle this Rolling updates you need follow thw next steps.

1. Go to [Compute Engine > Instance group].
2. Select the instance group that you want update.
3. At the top, you will find "UPDATE VMS".
4. Create a new template.
5. Update the VMs.

[image]

[Selective update](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/updating-selected-instances-in-a-mig) you can specifically target selected instances for an update. Use this method if you want to orchestrate the update manually.

So for the selective update you can control it and it will be helpful if you need to do some tests for an update.

For this update will be necessary to set up the new template with the following command in gcloud.

```
   gcloud compute instance-groups managed set-instance-template 
   INSTANCE_GROUP_NAME \
   --template=INSTANCE_TEMPLATE \
   [--zone=ZONE | --region=REGION]
```

To apply the update to specific instances, can be executed the following command.

```
    gcloud compute instance-groups managed update-instances 
    INSTANCE_GROUP_NAME \
    --instances INSTANCE_NAMES \
    --most-disruptive-allowed-action DISRUPTION_LEVEL \
    --minimal-action DISRUPTION_LEVEL
```